# SQL INSERT statement error

Tags: php, sql, insert

Hi there here is my SQL insert statement:

```
$customeraddress_query = "INSERT INTO  `customer_address` 
    (
    `apt_num`,
    `street1`,
    `street2`
    'city',
    'state',
    'date_stamp'
    )
    VALUES 
    (
    '$aptNum',
    '$street1',
    '$street2',
    '$city',
    '$state',
     now()
    )";
```

This is giving me the following error:

```
INSERT INTO `customer_address` ( `apt_num`, `street1`, `street2` 'city', 'state', 'date_stamp' ) VALUES ( '57', 'Col Street', 'x', 'v', 'x', now() )
```

Error:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''city', 'state', 'date_stamp' ) VALUES ' at line 6

I'm new to SQL and I was wondering if someone could help me with this. I suspect it's something to do with the right use of quotes.

But I cant seem to get these right.

Comment: Who the heck down voted the question and voted to close?  SO is starting to get full of a certain type of people, that prefer to criticise rather than help, and often are not actualy that astute themselves anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a comma(,) after the `street2` and `city`.

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO `customer_address` ( `apt_num`, `street1`, `street2`, `city`, `state`, `date_stamp` ) VALUES ( '57', 'Col Street', '', 'Waterloo', '', now() )
```

Comment: Thanks . This worked for me. Its important to put backticks since the insert didnt work without that.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the quotes from the table name.
You also should remove the quotes around the column names for city, state and date_stamp.  You are also missing a comma between street2 and city.  Should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO customer_address ( apt_num, street1, street2, city, state, date_stamp ) VALUES ( '$aptNum', '$street1', '$street2', '$city', '$state', now() )
```

Comment: Converting them to backticks would probably be better

Comment: That might be unique to MySQL because that's not part of the SQL standard.  What I gave complies with the standard.

Comment: Well my reasoning was that all the other column names provided have backticks. Even if it's for readability, he should use either one or the other, but using both would be more of a mess.

Comment: Personally, I don't often [] or `` my field names.  But if I were to argue the case as to whether they should be or not I would say that code should be formatted to quickly and easily visually distinguish between native SQL, UDF's, Tables, Fields, and strings/values.  One way to do this is to *always* mark fields with [] or ``.  I'd say that using them is more right than wrong.  (Also, their use at all in the OP's question, plus the php tag, evidences that this is very likely MySQL.)

Comment: Agreed with both.  For some reason backticks did not originally show for me.  I only saw the single quotes around the latter column names.

Answer (score 2):

You have a mixture of different quotes around your field names, and no `,` between street2 and city.

```
$customeraddress_query = "INSERT INTO customer_address ( `apt_num`, `street1`, `street2`, `city`, `state`, `date_stamp` ) VALUES ( '$aptNum', '$street1', '$street2', '$city', '$state', now() )";
```

Answer (score 1):

It look like you should add a comma after street2 and before city.

```
INSERT INTO 
`customer_address` 
( `apt_num`, 
  `street1`, 
  `street2`,
  'city', 
  'state', 
  'date_stamp' ) 
VALUES 
( '57', 
  'Col Street', 
  '', 
  'Waterloo', 
  '', 
  now() 
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use backticks (`` ` ``) when quoting table names, column names, etc, not quotes.

Use quotes (`"` or `'`) for strings only.

Answer (score 0):

Read up the other answers that have been posted. Another issue not addressed by those answers - you are missing the comma between street2 and city!